# Phonegap Geolocation API always getting error code 3

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap geolocation API in my phonegap android application.It always shows error code code 3,Timeout error.I am also try to change timeout variable value to increased,enableHighAccuracy to be true.But no change in result.But it will works on browser not runs in application.Give me the solution for this problem.

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css" type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css"
    type='text/css' />
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCJAbwOQjaVjDy9XJ0UEZCvTdZeW_atXak&sensor=false">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.10.2.min" type='text/javascript'></script>

<script>

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
$(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.phonegapNavigationEnabled = true;
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.mobile.loadingMessageTextVisible = true;
    $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage;
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Login').show();
    $('#Contacts').hide();
});




function success(name) {
    alert(name);
}

function error() {
    alert("error");
}

function login() {

    var name = $("#name").val();
    if (navigator.notification) {
        navigator.notification.alert("Welcome  " + name, alertDismissed, 'Sample App', 'Ok');
    } else {
        alert("Welcome  " + name);
    }
    var options = {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 8000,
        maximumAge: 10000
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
    $("#Login").hide();
    $("#Contacts").show();

}

function alertDismissed() {
    console.log("ok");
}



function onSuccess(position) {
    var latt1 = position.coords.latitude;
    var lont1 = position.coords.longitude; //alert(latt1+" "+lont1);
    var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(latt1, lont1);
    var mapOptions1 = {
        center: myLatlng1,
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions1);
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng1,
        map: map,
        title: "You are here! (at least within a " + position.coords.accuracy + " meter radius)"
    });
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        radius: 26000,
        strokeColor: "#00FF00",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#C0C0C0",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
    });
    marker1.setIcon("./images/blue_dot_circle.png");
        marker1.setMap(map);
}

function onError(error) {
    if (navigator.notification) {
        navigator.notification.alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n', alertDismissed, 'Sample App', 'Ok');
    } else {
        alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
}



function AlertConfirmed(buttonIndex) {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        device.exitApp();
        console.log(buttonIndex);
    } else {
        console.log(buttonIndex);
    }
}

function goHome() {
    navigator.app.loadUrl("http://www.google.co.in", {
        openExternal: true
    });
}    


</script>

<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"
    type='text/javascript'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" >
    <div id="Login">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b"
            data-tap-toggle="false" class="header" data-transition="none"
            id="myFixedHeader">
            <p>Sample Application</p>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="title">

                <div
                    style="width: 90%; padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 3%; padding-bottom: 1%;">
                    <input type="text" name="password" id="name" data-mini="true"
                        placeholder="Enter Your Name " value="" data-inline="true">
                </div>
                <center>
                    <div id="log"  onclick="login()">Login</div>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed"
            class="footer" data-transition="none" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <p onclick="goHome()">&copy;&nbsp;2014
                Sample App Reserved, LLC.</p>>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div  id="Contacts">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-tap-toggle="false"
            data-position="fixed" class="header" data-transition="none">
            <h3 id="htitle">Home Page</h3>

        </div>
        <div data-role="content" id="map_canvas" >


        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed"
            class="footer" data-transition="none" data-tap-toggle="false">
            <p onclick="goHome()">&copy;&nbsp;2014
                Sample App Reserved, LLC.</p>
        </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>


I have added Permissions INTERNET,FINE_LOCATION,COARSE_LOCATION in manifest file
and corrova 2.9.0.js
```

Comment: on which version of android

Comment: make sure that you added the permission in manifest.

Comment: In  browser it will show geolocation but not in APP                  I have tested all the versions like 2.1 to 4.2                       I had added permissions  of ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I made one mistake in config.xml.Now,I have added 

   <access origin="*"/> 
  <access origin="*://*.googleapis.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.gstatic.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.google.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.googleusercontent.com/*" subdomains="true" />

in my config.xml file.googlemap geolocation showed successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />` set in your android manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Make entry in app/res/xml/config.xml

Entry:

And in app/AndroidManifest.xml

Entry:

Also make sure that the enablehighAccuracy parameter is set to true.

Cheers!!