# Error code 3 Timeout when i try to get geolocation using Cordova in platform Android

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation, phonegap-plugins

index.js code:

```
// debug

function d(s) {
    console.log(s);
    $("#status").text(s);
}

// geo

function geoWin(pos) {
    d("geoWin(): "+pos.coords.latitude+", "+pos.coords.longitude+","+pos.coords.speed);
}

function geoFail(error) {
    d("geoFail(): "+error.code+": "+error.message);
}

function startGeoWatch() {
    d("startGeoWatch()");
    opt = {maximumAge: 0,timeout: 2000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
    watchGeo = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geoWin, geoFail, opt);
}

function stopGeoWatch() {
    d("stopGeoWatch()");
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchGeo);
}

// life cycle

function onPause() {
    d("onPause()");
    stopGeoWatch();
}

function onResume() {
    d("onResume()");
    startGeoWatch();
}

// init

function onDeviceReady() {
    d("onDeviceReady()");
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
    startGeoWatch();
}

function main() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
}

// main & globals
var watchGeo=null;
main();
```

my config.xml Code :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.terokarvinen.geo" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloCordova</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~2.2.0" />
</widget>
```

AndroidManifest code :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.terokarvinen.geo" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

while i try to run this application in firefox it gives my the exact geolocation.But when i try to run this same application in android device .It always give timeout expired.i dnt have any error in console.

> I had tested the my application is requested the GPS service of
>   android .I had checked that in location menu which have my application
>   in GPS request.

Comment: Could you share your project in github for testing the same in device?

Comment: sure i will upload a share a link to you.

Comment: Which browsers did you try on Android ?

Comment: i didn't tried o android browser  i had build it to android application then test it on android device .It works fine on browser .

Comment: @HassanALi What about sharing the project link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [myriads of similar questions on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android%20geolocation), it seems the Cordova geolocation plugin has [issues especially on Android](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5977). It seems the solution is to:

1. Remove the geolocation plugin as follows:

`cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.geolocation`.

Your application will fall back on the standard HTML5 `navigator.geolocation` functionality.

2. Of course, double check your location services are on, that your device has coverage (isn't in a building with thick walls, etc. If it is, maybe set enableHighAccuracy to `false` and set a greater timeout).
3. Ensure you have the following permissions by adding these lines in your manifest:

`< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />`

In addition, give your application internet access so it can access Wifi and cellphone antennas:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

I am unable to try this myself, but you should have better luck after doing this.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: The geolocation plugin on android uses the HTML5 implementation, it just adds the permissions

Comment: sorry it didn't work out for me.Thanks for your time @ThomCunningham

Answer (score 0):

```
<access origin="*"/> 
<access origin="*://*.googleapis.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.gstatic.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.google.com/*" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="*://*.googleusercontent.com/*" subdomains="true" />
```

Try with above Code .place this on config.xml .
 Check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23129438/6229597)

Comment: check please explain why i have to put this code in my config ?